# Where do I find the svn checkout files on Mac using terminal

Tags: file, svn, terminal

I am running Mac Lion 10.7.  I used terminal to execute the following:

```
svn checkout http://android-log-collector.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ android-log-collector-read-only
```

everything appeared to checkout correctly:

```
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector/.classpath
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector/project.properties
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector/assets
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector/.project
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector/AndroidManifest.xml
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector/src
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector/res
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector/res/values
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector/res/values/strings.xml
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector/res/drawable
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector/res/drawable/launcher_icon.png
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector/res/drawable-hdpi
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector/res/drawable-hdpi/launcher_icon.png
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector/res/drawable-ldpi
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector/res/drawable-ldpi/launcher_icon.png
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector/res/drawable-mdpi
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector/res/drawable-mdpi/launcher_icon.png
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector/res/drawable-xhdpi
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector/res/drawable-xhdpi/launcher_icon.png
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector/res/layout
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/.classpath
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/project.properties
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/assets
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/.project
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/AndroidManifest.xml
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/src
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/src/com
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/src/com/xtralogic
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/src/com/xtralogic/android
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/src/com/xtralogic/android/logcollector
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/src/com/xtralogic/android/logcollector/usage
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/src/com/xtralogic/android/logcollector/usage/Main.java
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/res
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/res/values
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/res/values/strings.xml
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/res/drawable
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/res/drawable/icon.png
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/res/drawable-hdpi
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/res/drawable-ldpi
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/res/drawable-mdpi
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/res/drawable-xhdpi
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/res/layout
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-usage/res/layout/main.xml
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/.classpath
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/project.properties
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/assets
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/.project
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/proguard-project.txt
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/AndroidManifest.xml
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/src
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/src/com
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/src/com/xtralogic
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/src/com/xtralogic/android
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/src/com/xtralogic/android/logcollector
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/src/com/xtralogic/android/logcollector/lib
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/src/com/xtralogic/android/logcollector/lib/SendLogActivity.java
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/libs
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/libs/android-support-v4.jar
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/res
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/res/values
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/res/values/strings.xml
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/res/drawable-hdpi
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_search.png
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/res/drawable-ldpi
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/res/drawable-mdpi
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_search.png
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/res/drawable-xhdpi
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_search.png
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/res/layout
A    android-log-collector-read-only/android-log-collector-lib/build.xml
```

**But I cannot find the files.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has checked-out the files to your current working directory, so typing "ls" in the terminal should show a "android-log-collector-read-only/" directory.  To figure out where you are, use the pwd command

A

Answer (score 0):

Are you inexperienced with command line shell tools?  If so, Google for Unix shell tutorial.

I'm not sure about Lion, but on Mountain Lion, my Mac was at first configured to hide my home directory - /Users/mike for me - but instead direct me always to my Documents folder - ~/Users/mike/Documents.

But when the Unix shell starts up - bash on Mac OS X by default - it starts up in your home directory.  That means that by default, the Finder won't show it.

There's a couple ways to deal with it.  One was is to use the "cd" - Change Directory - command in the Terminal to set your current directory to Documents:

```
$ cd Documents
$ svn checkout ...
```

You'll now find your checked out folder in your documents folder.

Alternatively, use the Finder Preferences, under the Finder menu just to the right of your Apple menu, to add your home directory to the list of folders at the left top of your Finder windows.  You can also set the Finder so that by default, new windows display your home directory rather than your Documents folder.

I found this enforced Documents folder to be very annoying until I learned how to set the Preferences.  But the typical Mac users are novices, who don't know how to organize their files and folders.  I've been struggling for many years to teach my mother how to navigate the Mac filesystem, without any success at all.  If she saves a document to the wrong folder, she will never find it again!